# Safari does not play videos but has sound

Tags: javascript, html, ios, macos, video

With Safari on Mac/iOS the video does not play but has sound. Only the first frame plays. When Tabbing to another window or minimizing, it solves this issue. The video tag is being added to the page via JavaScript.

Cant show the code as this is being developed for a company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by Safari not handling the generated video tag via JavaScript. I was able to test and solve this by hard coding the tag into a second page and detecting safari and using an iFrame for only safari while Chrome/Edge/Firefox/Opera are all using the generated HTML.

Cant show the code as this is being developed for a company. However, this should save others time as I did not run across anything online about a solution and it is only Safari that has the issue.